# c macro __LINE__, __FILE__, __func__ equivalent in gnat ada

Tags: c, macros, ada, gnat

Is there an equivalent in [gnat](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnat/) [ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29) for the [c macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `__func__`? These are quite helpful in error messages to quickly find the error in the code. Maybe there is another concept to archive the same goal.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have an installation on hand to check, but the documentation says that the package [GNAT.Source_Info](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gnat_rm/GNAT_002eSource_005fInfo-_0028g-souinf_002eads_0029.html) "provides subprograms that give access to source code information known at compile time, such as the current file name and line number." and adacore has the [spec for the package](https://www2.adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/rts/g-souinf__ads.htm) (via Christoph)

Comment: see http://adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/rts/g-souinf__ads.htm for documentation

Comment: Code to get `file:line, procedure`:

`with GNAT.Source_Info;`

`Put_Line(GNAT.Source_Info.Source_Location & ", " & NAT.Source_Info.Enclosing_Entity);`

Comment: Fixed Christoph's link in the answer:  https://www2.adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/rts/g-souinf__ads.htm

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` and the other `__THING__`s are features of the C pre-processor which is not something that ada has.  You could probably jury-rig a simple perl-script (or similar) to pre-run your code through to simulate `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` but `__func__` would be more difficult because it would mean actually parsing the code.

Ah, turns out that it exists in GNAT.  Example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO
GNAT.Source_Info;
use  Ada.Text_IO
GNAT.Source_Info;

procedure source_error is
  -- example of GNAT.Source_Info.Source_Location
  i : integer;
  j : integer := 0;
begin
  i := 5/j; -- division by zero
exception when others =>
  put_line( standard_error
Source_Location & ": exception raised" );
end source_error;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to print stack traces on exception. There's some GNAT binder argument to enable the storage of stack traces (-E?), and then you can print them with the Ada.Exceptions package. There's also a package to print the stack at any point or from an exception occurrence (I always have a last resort handler for all tasks). See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stack_traces#Ada

In my experience stack traces on exception are ideal to pinpoint problems.